# Least stressful way to travel from NYC to GYE, Ecuador?

Tags: air-travel, transit, ecuador

The flights from NYC to Guayaquil (GYE) are long and on airlines with only modest user ratings.

I have time to stop over en route.  So, I am looking for recommendations for locations that have good flights both to and from NYC and GYE. The goal is fly highly rated airlines and to minimize the stress of travel by splitting the one long trip into two shorter trips.

Answer (score 3):

While @Hilmar answer is probably better about non-stop flights, if you want to break you flights up, the natural location to do this would be Miami.  There are multiple options for the NYC->MIA leg and the MIA->GYE leg.

But in doing so you are trading a "long" flight (7 Hrs) for a 3Hr and a 4Hr flight, plus an additional going through TSA security at MIA.  So all you would be achieving is moving the stress from one type to another.  In addition, you now have to factor in the weather at MIA, and the reliability of 2 different aircraft vs a single one.

Comment: Almost certainly you would not need to pass through security at MIA coming from New York as long is it's on a single airline.

Comment: @AndrewRay The OP talked about taking a break and "stop over".  I took this to mean that they wanted to leve the airport

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what airline ratings you are looking at and what exactly you are looking for. Most 5 star airline (depending on the rating system) are Asian and they don't serve GYE.

Which airline to choose depends a lot on whether you want to fly economy or business. As a general rule, business in a lot rated airline is still going to be a lot better than economy on a highly rated one. Most mainline carrier have really compressed their economy to claustrophobic dimensions.

Your best shot in Economy would probably Jetblue: non-stop from NYC or through Fort Lauderdale. Non-stop is a little less than 7 hours so its very similar to a transcontinental flight. Personally I would take economy in JetBlue any day over, say, Lufthansa or United .

Things are a bit different if you want to fly business. Most business class will be just fine for such a relatively short trip. If you want to do lie flat, you may have to detour through Lima. Central America, Colombia, Ecuador, etc are typically not served with lie flats.

Comment: yeah a nonstop on JetBlue is as good as it gets on routes like this. the route is also served nonstop by Avianca, which is perfectly fine and certainly less stressful than a layover in Mexico  or Panama or whatever other city is in between New York and Guayaquil